# C:\Users\Public\ for sensitive data

Tags: windows

Installing a MS Windows based system that is to handle various sensitive data (accounting, personnel etc.). Somewhat to my surprise it consistently want to put everything under

```
c:\Users\Public\
```

where it is going to store reports, SQL databases, documents and so on. Is this a poor choice of location for such data?

Believe I can hack the system to accept using a custom path where I can set group access or the like if/when (selected) others are to have access. Would this be worth the work? (Have not used Windows for a long, long time.)

Have spoken with the provider about this, but they seem to have no advice regarding the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Public' profile allows anyone who can log into the system access to the contents. You may still be able to limit it with NTFS permissions, but if you are trying to do proper access controls via NTFS on the files you should really use a folder outside of the user profiles in general. Then you can block inheritance and set your own permissions.